# How to assign my custom permission level to my TestGroup?

Tags: development, sharepoint-server

I have created one group Name: TestGroup 
and one permission level Name: Custompermisionlevel

How can I assign the permission level(Custompermisionlevel) to my group programmatically?

I'm using this code:

```
public void SetPermissionsToGroup()
    {
        using (var site = new SPSite("http://sp2010:8888"))
        {
            using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                //Get group and group roles
                var group = web.SiteGroups["TestGroup"];
                var roles = new SPRoleAssignment(group);                   

                //Add another role
                roles.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Custompermisionlevel));
                roles.Update();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am not getting my Custompermisionlevel in SPRoleType. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

getting this error:Cannot update a permission level assignment that is not part of a permission level assignment collection.

Answer (score 5):

Aishwarya,

You can get Role Definition object by:

```
SPRoleDefinition myRoleDefinition = oWeb.RoleDefinitions["CustomRoleDefinitionDisplayName"];
```

Or you can get custom Role Definition by using Linq:

```
SPRoleDefinition myRoleDefinition = oWeb.RoleDefinitions.Cast<SPRoleDefinition>().Where(x => x.Name == "CustomRoleDefinitionName").FirstOrDefault();
```

Plese make sure you add `using System.Linq;` at the top.. and replace `CustomRoleDefinitionName` with your role definition name

Once you get the Role Definition, you can use it as following:

```
var roles = new SPRoleAssignment(group);                   

//Add another role
roles.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(myRoleDefinition);
roles.Update();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get your custom permission level as below:

```
roleDefinition = web.RoleDefinitions["YourCustomPermLevelName"];
```

Your error is about something else I think. On what securable object do you want to give your custom permission level to the group? I think you can't and don't have to call roles.Update() like that.

> You can only call the Update method for an SPRoleAssignment object that is part of an SPRoleAssignmentCollection that in turn is bound to a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation object that implements the ISecurableObject interface (for example, SPWeb).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sproleassignment.update.aspx

Let's say you want to give your custom permission level to the group for the site (can be a list, item,..). Then you can do the following:

```
public void SetPermissionsToGroup()
{
    using (var site = new SPSite("http://sp2010:8888"))
    {
        using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            var group = web.SiteGroups["TestGroup"];
            SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(group);
            SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = new SPRoleDefinition();
            roleDefinition = web.RoleDefinitions["YourCustomPermLevelName"];
            SPRoleDefinitionBindingCollection roleDefinitionBindingCollection = new SPRoleDefinitionBindingCollection();
            roleDefinitionBindingCollection.Add(roleDefinition);
            roleAssignment.ImportRoleDefinitionBindings(roleDefinitionBindingCollection);
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            web.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;             
        }
    }
}
```

http://naimmurati.wordpress.com/2011/02/27/set-permissions-on-sharepoint-list-and-items-programmatically/